# Sigmajs - Collapse Nodes Best Practice

Tags: graph-visualization

I'm trying to work out best practice for collapsing nodes in a GraphDB/graph visualization UI.

[image]

Collapsing `Cypher` collapses the 3 red nodes.

Collapsing `SQL` collapses 6 purple nodes.

Collapsing `NEO 4J BI Connector` collapses 5 blue nodes...BUT what happens to `Cypher` and `SQL` nodes and their edges when I do that?

Should they also collapse?

What happens if `Tableau` node is connected to `Data Analyst` node? How should the collapse function/UI handle that problem?